# How to solve Node mon crashing problem when connecting mongo DB using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nodemon

Node mon app crashing problem when connecting Mongo DB using Nodejs

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If this happens while setting up mongodb ,then this is because you have not added your IP in the whitelist in the MongoDB Atlas app.After you add that ,you are good to go